# SQLite db size too big

Tags: .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm creating a DB using SQLite from .NET and then inserting 1500 records (15 columns, only 3 with information). At this point the database file size is 73mb!! (huge for the amount of information involved).

If I open *SQLite Administrator*, and do a *Clear Database*, it shrinks to only 142kb.

Why is it doing that? Is there anyway to avoid it?
Either way, is there a way to shrink the DB file from .NET (I'm using System.Data.SQLite, which uses Finistar under the hood) ?

Comment: Did you find what was the cause of this increase in size?

Comment: I think that's the way it works.  You just need to do what @uthark suggested. For me, that was a good enough solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can execute **[VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)**  and **[REINDEX](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_reindex.html)** on the database in order to shrink its size.